# A puzzle that needs to be programmed with Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, wxpython, ipython

I'm a beginner in Python ... In fact, I'm beginner in programming. Python is the first programming language I started to learn.

I had received a puzzle which I liked to solve by writing a program to do it (as a practice) , but I couldn't.

The puzzle was the following:

Say you have 100 people, standing like they make a circle, each one of them has a number, the first one carries the number 1 , the second one carries the number 2 , ... , and so on ending with the last one who's carrying the number 100 ... The first one was given a sword to kill the one who has the number which is greater than his with 1 ... Which means he kills number 2 ... And then he gives the sword to the next one who is number 3 ... And the process keeps going until only one gets to stay alive! ... Who is that one?

I tried to solve it manually , and it turned out the answer was 73 ... Number 73 is the one who stays alive!

But, do you have any idea how to program it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried.

Comment: but who does number 100 kill when you get to him?

Comment: I got  a program to do most of it, but I end up with this: `[97, 1, 9, 17, 25, 33, 41, 49, 57, 65, 73, 81, 89]` circle. Number 97 cannot kill anybody here. What do you want to happen when the sword is handed to number 97. **EDIT** I googled the puzzle, it looks like it doesn't work by killing whoever has the number greater than you, whoever has the sword just kills whoever is next in line

Comment: @Racialz, yes exactly! ... Sorry, for not explaining it right!

Comment: check out my answer, I'm pretty sure I solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is a fun problem and in my opinion is a great excuse to use pythons .pop function.

```
circle = list(range(1,101))
#100 people numbered 1-100


while len(circle) > 1: #run this code as long as the circle has more than one person
    print(str(circle[0]) + " kills " + str(circle[1]))
    survivor = circle[0] #save the survivor to a variable
    circle.pop(1) #remove the person killed from the list
    circle.pop(0) #remove the person who survives from the list
    #now the new start of the list is whoever is next in line

    circle.append(survivor) #re-add the survivor to the list at the end

print(str(circle[0]) + "is the winner") #print out the survivor
```

This works because the "start" of the circle is always circle[0], when two people fight, both the winner and loser are removed from the list, making circle[0] whoever is next in line. Then the winner is re-added to the end of the list, putting him at the back

I added a couple lines to print out the full evolution of the circle and uploaded it to a pastebin http://pastebin.com/raw/z6ghuqE3

Comment: That was awesome! :-)
Thank you very much ... I'll try to study and understand your program!
Where did you learn Python?

Comment: I started a couple weeks ago with googles python class (all available on youtube): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKTZoB2Vjuk but I have a lot of background in other languages so it was easy to pickup

Comment: You're a genius! :-)  .... I'll check your link ... And thank you for everything!

Comment: That was a mistake ... I changed it back ;-)

Comment: That's my first post ... I thought i could mark both of your answers ... Because I think he helped as well

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you solved it by yourself... How? Can you make Python do it the same way ?

Because you are doing this as a learning exercise let's think about a few different things

How are you going to keep track of who is alive
How are you going to know when to stop killing people (that made me laugh) and
How are you going to pass the sword

To get you on the right track I would suggest googling something like "iteration in Python" or "Python control structures "

Because another answer has provided an iterative approach In my solution I will use recursion to solve the problem, where the function calls itself until it reaches the exit condition.

```
numPeople = 100
theCircle = list(range(1, numPeople + 1))

#Solve with recursion
def massacreRecursion(theCircle):
    #Exit condition
    if len(theCircle) == 2:
        theCircle.pop(1) #kill the last victim so len(theCircle) == 1 is True
        print(theCircle[0]) #Print the survivor
    else:
        theCircle.pop(1) #kill some poor pleb
        theCircle.append( theCircle.pop( 0 ))  #rotate the circle left 1 effectively passing the sword right
        massacreRecursion(theCircle) #do it again and again and again...

#enter the recursion
massacreRecursion(theCircle)
```

Comment: I'll do that! :-)   .... And thank you very much! .... Where do you think is best for me to learn Python?